# How can I find efficiently which lat lon is closest to a specific point from a set of coordinates?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

If I have an arraylist of coordinates i.e. lat/lon how can I find which one is closest to a specific (other) lat lot location?
I.e. what is an good way to find given A(lat, lon) and ((lat, lon), (lat,lon)...etc) which coordinate on the list is the closest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) or [Location.distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))

Comment: What does this mean? `The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].` from the doc? What is initial bearing and final bearing?

Comment: For example, you can use `Location.distanceTo` to implement a custom `Comparator` and then call `Collections.sort(yourListArray, yourCustomComparator)`. As a result `yourArrayList` will be sorted by the distance. The nearest will be `yourArrayList.get(0)`

Comment: What is the `bearing`?